# How to put underline under button name

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have button with name "itemname", and now I want to put underline just under character "i" in "itemname", but I don't know how I should do this. Could anyone please tell me how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use an ampersand character (`&`) to do that:

```
yourButton.Text = "&itemname";
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az5a73z1.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an "&" to left of the letter you want to underline.
So, a button with text "&itemname" will have the "i" underlined.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want Alt+I to click the button?

Have you tried changing the label text from `itemname` to `&itemname`?

Answer (score 1):

You should add an "&" to left of the letter you want to underline. So, a button with text "&itemname" will have the "i" underlined.
and you can get focused to the button by pressing **"alt+i"**